# Find and name specific values in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates

I have a dataframe df_1() with coordinates:

```
 lat      lon  
54.52501 6.295359
54.52501 6.295293
54.52502 6.294764
54.52503 6.294698
54.52503 6.294302
54.52504 6.294236
54.43791 6.386598
54.43790 6.386656
54.43790 6.386714
54.43790 6.386831
54.43790 6.386948
54.43789 6.387001 
54.43789 6.387124
54.43789 6.387183
54.43789 6.387241
54.52533 6.391403
54.52534 6.391336
54.52534 6.391270
```

Furthermore I have a second dataframe df_2 () with coordinates of a windfarm. These coordinates describe the corners of a polygon (= windfram area).

```
  lat_GTI        lon_GTI
  54.498434     6.315664
  54.541046     6.315695
  54.541013     6.416187
  54.451969     6.388373
```

What I want to do: add another column to df_1() which specifies whether the coordinates of df_1 are within the windfarm polygon or not.

I have already tried something. But it doesn't work.

```
df_1$test1 <- df_1 [df_1 == df_2] <- "OWF"
```

Comment: Several packages implement 'point in polygon' algorithms; e.g. `sp::point.in.polygon(df_1$lat, df_1$lon, df_2$lat_GTI, df_2$lon_GTI)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see those four points as a rectangle. The last longitude is off. But, assuming you have a rectangle, you can use something like this:

```
min_lat_GTI = min(df_2$lat_GTI)
max_lat_GTI = max(df_2$lat_GTI)
min_lon_GTI = min(df_2$lon_GTI)
max_lon_GTI = max(df_2$lon_GTI)

df_1$test1 <- ifelse(df_1$lat >= min_lat_GTI & df_1$lat <= max_lat_GTI & df_1$lon >= min_lon_GTI & df_1$lon <= max_lon_GTI), 'IN', 'OUT')
```

If you want to have a more complex condition evaluation to determine whether a point is inside a polygon, you can write a function that tests for that and use that function inside the ifelse() statement.

UPDATE:

To use a function, you would do something like this:

```
isInside <- function(lat, lon) {
  # Bunch of code that tests whether the lat/lon are inside the polygon
  # return TRUE if inside, FALSE otherwise
}

df_1$test1 <- ifelse(isInside(df_1$lat, df_1$lon), 'IN', 'OUT')
```

Comment: Your're wright. This windpark area is more likely polygon. Unfortunately, I have never written a function. So I'm not sure how the function has to look like at last.